# How secure is storing JWT Token in the browser?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, jwt

I am implementing a token based authentication using JWT and from what I have read so far, the way to store it throughout the session is through localstorage / cookie. Since that value is in clear text to someone who can use a dev toolbar to see the cookies, what's to stop someone from using that token and sending it on endpoints that are publicly exposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal cases, the user that is able to get the token via the dev toolbar is the same user that was able to aquire the token in a regular way. So that should not be a security problem.

Each JWT token should contain an audience (aud) claim, that is checked by every resource. So the token can't be used to access endpoints for which it wasn't issued.